# Boost simple SELECT performance of SQLite database

Tags: performance, sqlite, rsqlite

I'm using a SQLite database (1GB+) in which there's only one table of stacked financial tick time series. I'm using RSQLite package to connect to the database. My situation is very simple: select a subset of data from one date to the other, e.g. from `20140101` to `20140930`. Therefore the query is simple too:

```
SELECT * FROM DATA WHERE YMD BETWEEN 20140101 AND 20140930
```

The data is stored on a SSD but the reading time looks still slow. Are there some ways or tips to boost the performance of such simple subsetting query?

The database has 14 columns and on automatic index.

Comment: How many columns? Any indexes?

Comment: I'd imagine adding an index on ymd would help.